# Sort order for group in Organic Groups view "OG all user group content"

Tags: 7, views, panels, organic-groups

I am using Drupal 7 & Organic Groups 7.x-2.7.
I am using one of the "Views" that comes with Organic Groups called
OG all user group content, 
which shows the content from all the group the current user belongs to.

I am trying to control how the Groups show up and can't seem to get it to sort.

Here is how the groups automatically show up

[image]

I would like the Amigo group to show up before the Authenticated group.
I've tried a couple things, such as 
sorting by "OG membership: Entity id"
and sorting by "OG membership: Og membership ID"
but nothing seems to change the order that the groups are displayed in.

Anyone know how to do this?

Here is an image of the admin UI for the view:

[image]